# Delete from Array in Function

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my Class I declared an Array

```
myUsers = new Array();
```

Where I want to Add Usernames, unique.
So i thought I would check if the ArrayLenght is 0, if yes, add a User.
Which works fine.
I if a Username wants to be added, which exists in the Array, it should be deleted.
But this way,
If I add one User the console says ["User1"]
If I try to add another one (another one User2) the console says ["User1", empty]
Can't get behind that...

```
isChecked(e) {
     var usersArray = this.myUsers;
     console.log(usersArray.length);


 if(this.myUsers.length == 0) {
      console.log("is 0");
      this.myUsers.push(e);
    } else {
      console.log("is not 0");
      for (var i= 0; i < this.myUsers.length; i++) {
        if (this.myUsers[i] == e) {
           console.log("is in array");
           delete this.myUsers[i];
          } else {
            this.myUsers.push(e);
          }
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: Consider using a  `Set` instead of an array.

Comment: This seems to work. But, My Data is coming from a Form with Checkboxes. I want to delete the Name if the Checkbox is unchecked. That's why I wanted to delete a Name wich is in the Array. Why is Set better?

Comment: With Set it works fine.    if(this.mySet.has(e)) {
      console.log("item in set");
      this.mySet.delete(e); 
    } else {
      this.mySet.add(e);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Replace `delete this.myUsers[i];` with `this.myUsers.splice(i, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to delete the value. That will just clear the value. What you want instead is to truncate the array. To do that, use the `splice()` function:

```
this.myUsers.splice(i, 1);
```

The first parameter is the index to start deleting. The second is how many values to delete (in this case, 1). It mutates the actual array, so no need to assign it back or anything.

Comment: Okay, did that, but still not working... now it does not add another user at all after calling the function again.